# Parsing JSON correctly in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Alright, totally new to Android Studio, but I've been trying to parse backpack.tf's json in Android Studio, and I'm a bit stuck.

Here is a little snippet of json I would try to parse:

```
{
"response": {
    "success": 1,
    "current_time": 1448658000,
    "items": {
        "A Color Similar to Slate": {
            "last_updated": 1448654419,
            "quantity": 48,
            "value": 99
        },
```

And the code I'm using to parse JSON is here:

```
   String finalJSON = buffer.toString();
   JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
   JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("A Color Similar to Slate");

  JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(3);

  int price = finalObject.getInt("value");

  return "$" + price;
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: is Gson library allowed?

Comment: You may use gson or jackson kind of util lib.

Comment: I've never heard of GSON! Is there a good tutorial to check out for it?

Comment: probably documentation on github ;) look at my answer

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please be more specific.

Comment: When I run my JSONTask class that I made, it'll grab the json and display it just fine. But when I try to parse the JSON, it'll return an error in console, saying: org.json.JSONException: No value for A Color Similar to Slate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You have JSON:

```
   {"response":{
        "success": 1,
                "current_time": 1448658000,
                "items": {
            "A Color Similar to Slate": {
                "last_updated": 1448654419,
                        "quantity": 48,
                        "value": 99
            },
        }
    }
    }
```

Code:

```
  String finalJSON =buffer.toString();;
    JSONObject parentObject = null;
    try {
        parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
        JSONObject objectA_Color=parentObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("items").getJSONObject("A Color Similar to Slate");

       int  value=objectA_Color.getInt("value");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create some (custom, adjusted to your needs) `Model` class

```
public class Model {
    private String title;
    private List<String> authors;
//getters fields, magic ...
}
```

2) Parse your JSON (

```
public static final String JSON_PATH = "/Users/dawid/Workspace/Test/test.json";

Gson gson = new Gson();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSON_PATH));
Model model = gson.fromJson(br, Model.class);
```

OR

1) Parse it with JSON Parser

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSON_PATH));
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject object = parser.parse(br).getAsJsonObject();
```

Both ways Require GSON library https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: This doesn't answer his specific question. He might as well go look at other GSON examples. I love GSON too, but I hate that it is automatically the answer for any JSON parsing question. A third party lib isn't always the right answer.

Comment: I've suggested one of solution. Probably not the best one, but it solves OP problem. If there will be another solution i will give it +1 if it will work too and if it will be proper

Comment: I'm not sure if i want to implement this, i already built a JSONTask class,to fetch the JSON file, I just need to parse it.

Comment: can you use it as model?